# Cookie will set, but won't remain set

Tags: php, cookies

I know this has been asked many times before, and I've read and tried every suggestion I've found.

I set a cookie in a separate file with the following code:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $q = $_SESSION['qty'];
    setcookie ("quantity", $q, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
    $_COOKIE['quantity'] = $qty;
    if(isset($_COOKIE['quantity'])) {
        print_r("set");
    }
    else print_r("not set");

?>
```

It print's "set" every time, indicating to me it has been set. However, in a different php page I test for the cookie with the following code...

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE["quantity"])) {
      include("functions/setQty.php");
}
```

...and it always takes me to the setQty page, indicating to me that it isn't set (which other issues verify that it's not). What am I missing?

Comment: If you are using chrome, check the dev tools and go to the application tab, select cookies and check if it is set.

Comment: Check your log for `Headers already sent` errors from the first script.